# Can a line intersect a sphere at more than two points in a Real Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have shown using the property of inner products that a line in a real Hilbert space can only intersect a sphere at most two points but the second part of the question I am stuck on. It is asking if this is also true in a Real Banach space and if not to give a counterexample. I am not really sure how to tackle the second part of the problem.

Comment: What are you calling a line? $\{t \vec{v} : t\in\Bbb R\} $ where $\vec{v} $ is assumed to be a unit vector? Can it be shifted from the origin?

Comment: For my purposes a line in a Banach space B would be a set of the form $\{x:x=x_1+ty_1\}$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1,y_1 \in B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\|x\|_\infty = \operatorname{max}(|x_1|, |x_2|)$.  Draw a picture of the unit sphere.

The norm $\|x\|_1 = |x_1| + |x_2|$ also works.

By similar logic, you can show that $\ell^1, L^1, \ell^\infty, L^\infty$ are also counterexamples.